# C++ Pointer and Object Initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers, data-structures

I'm designing a data structure that looks like this:

[image: My Data Structure Assignment]

I'm using redirected input to get the data needed to fill the data structure.
Here is the code. I know it's a lot to slog through but the important stuff is near the bottom of the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class DT>
class Cell {
protected:
    DT* info;
    Cell<DT>* right;
public:
    Cell();
    Cell(const DT& info);
    Cell(const DT& info, Cell<DT>* next);
    Cell(const Cell<DT>& copy);
    void copy(const Cell<DT>& copy);
    ~Cell();
    void operator=(const Cell<DT>& check);
    bool isEmpty();
    DT getInfo();
    Cell<DT>* next();
    int size();
    DT& find(const DT& key);
    DT& infoAt(int position);
    void add(const DT& object);
    void insertAt(const DT& newObj, int position);
    Cell<DT>* setNext(Cell<DT>* next);
    DT remove();
    DT removeAt(int position);
};

template <class DT>
Cell<DT>::Cell()
{
    info = NULL;
}

template <class DT>
Cell<DT>::Cell(const DT& info) {
    this->info = new DT(info);
    right = NULL;
}

template <class DT>
Cell<DT>::Cell(const DT& info, Cell<DT>* next) {
    this->info = new DT(info);
    right = next;
}

template <class DT>
Cell<DT>::~Cell() {
    if (info != NULL) {
        delete info;
        info = NULL;
    }
    if (right != NULL) {
        delete right;
        right = NULL;
    }
}

template <class DT>
void Cell<DT>::copy(const Cell<DT>& copy) {
    if (copy.info == NULL) info = NULL;
    else info = new DT(*(copy.info));
    if (copy.right == NULL) right = NULL;
    else right = new Cell<DT>(*(copy.right));
}

template <class DT>
Cell<DT>::Cell(const Cell<DT>& copy) {
    this->copy(copy);
}

template <class DT>
void Cell<DT>::operator=(const Cell<DT>& check) {
    if (info != NULL) delete info;
    if (right != NULL) delete right;
    copy(check);
}

template <class DT>
bool Cell<DT>::isEmpty() {
    return (info == NULL);
}

template <class DT>
DT Cell<DT>::getInfo() {
    return *info;
}

template <class DT>
Cell<DT>* Cell<DT>::next() {
    return right;
}

template <class DT>
int Cell<DT>::size() {
    if (next == NULL) {
        if (info == NULL) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }
    else return 1 + right->size();
}

template <class DT>
DT& Cell<DT>::find(const DT& key) {
    if (key == *info) return *info;
    return right->find(key);
}

template <class DT>
DT& Cell<DT>::infoAt(int position) {
    if (isEmpty()) return NULL;
    if (position == 0) return *info;
    if (right == NULL) return NULL;
    return right->infoAt(position - 1);
}

template <class DT>
void Cell<DT>::add(const DT& object) {
    if (info == NULL) info = new DT(object);
    else {
        Cell<DT>* newList = new Cell<DT>(*info, right);
        *info = object;
        right = newList;
    }
}

template <class DT>
void Cell<DT>::insertAt(const DT& newObj, int position) {
    if (position == 0) add(newObj);
    else {
        if (right == NULL) right = new Cell<DT>(newObj);
        else right->insertAt(newObj, position - 1);
    }
}

template <class DT>
Cell<DT>* Cell<DT>::setNext(Cell<DT>* next) {
    Cell<DT>* temp = this->right;
    this->right = (Cell<DT>*) next;
    return temp;
}

template <class DT>
DT Cell<DT>::remove() {
    DT temp = *info;
    delete info;
    if (right == NULL) info = NULL;
    else {
        Cell<DT>*  oldnext = right;
        info = right->info;
        right = right->right;
        oldnext->info = NULL;
        oldnext->next = NULL
            delete oldnext;
    }
    return temp;
}

template <class DT>
DT Cell<DT>::removeAt(int position) {
    if (position == 0) return remove();
    return right->removeAt(position - 1);
}

template <class DT1, class DT2>
class CellNode {
protected:
    DT1* info;
    Cell<DT2>* myCell;
public:
    CellNode();
    CellNode(DT1 title, DT2* info);
    CellNode(DT1 title);
    CellNode(DT2* info);
};

template <class DT1, class DT2>
CellNode<DT1, DT2>::CellNode() {
    info = new DT1();
    myCell = new Cell<DT2>();
}

template <class DT1, class DT2>
CellNode<DT1, DT2>::CellNode(DT1 title, DT2* info) {
    this->info = new DT1(title);
    myCell = new Cell<DT2>(info[0]);
    for (int i = 1; info[i] != NULL; i++) myCell->add(info[i]);
}

template <class DT1, class DT2>
CellNode<DT1, DT2>::CellNode(DT1 title) {
    this->info = new DT1(title);
    myCell = new Cell<DT2>();
}

template <class DT1, class DT2>
CellNode<DT1, DT2>::CellNode(DT2* info) {
    this->info = new DT1();
    if (myCell == NULL) {
        myCell = new Cell<DT2>(info[0]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; info[i] != NULL; i++) myCell->add(info[i]);
}

template <class DT1, class DT2>
class MasterCell {
protected:
    CellNode<DT1, DT2>* myCellNodes;
    int cellsFilled;
public:
    MasterCell();
    MasterCell(int size);
    void add(DT1 title, DT2* info);
};

template<class DT1, class DT2>
MasterCell<DT1, DT2>::MasterCell() {
    //This can't do anything.
}

template<class DT1, class DT2>
MasterCell<DT1, DT2>::MasterCell(int size) {
    myCellNodes = new CellNode<DT1, DT2>[size];
    cellsFilled = 0;
}

template<class DT1, class DT2>
void MasterCell<DT1, DT2>::add(DT1 title, DT2* info) {
    myCellNodes[0] = new CellNode<DT1, DT2>(title, info);
}

int main() {
    MasterCell<char, char*>* master;
    char * check = new char[100000];
    char* buffer;
    int size = 0;
    int lineAmount = 0;
    int cellCounter = 0;
    while (!cin.eof()) {
        cin.get(check[size]);
        size++;
    }
    size;
    buffer = new char[size - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        buffer[i] = check[i];
        if (buffer[i] == '\n') lineAmount++;
    }
    delete[] check;
    lineAmount++;
    cout << size << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        cout << buffer[i];
    }
    master = new MasterCell<char, char*>(lineAmount);
    cout << endl << lineAmount << endl;
    char* test = new char[5];
    test = "hello";
    char** test2 = new char*[2];
    test2[0] = new char[5];
    test2[0] = "hello";
    test2[1] = new char[5];
    test2[1] = "world";
    master->add((*test), test2);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I'm having has to do with MasterCell's add method. First I have created the myCellNodes array in the initializer of MasterCell. Next, the I want to add nodes to that array using MasterCell's add method except I get an error message when I try to compile and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

This line is the one that gives me trouble:

```
myCellNodes[0] = new CellNode<DT1, DT2>(title, info);
```

This is the error I get:

Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'CellNode *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Note: A lot of the junk in main is me interpreting the redirected input in such a way that I don't have to deal with re-sizing arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want to keep a dynamic array of pointers:

`CellNode<DT1, DT2>* myCellNodes;`

should be:

```
CellNode<DT1, DT2>** myCellNodes;
```

and

```
myCellNodes = new CellNode<DT1, DT2>[size];
```

should be

```
myCellNodes = new CellNode<DT1, DT2> *[size];
```

Comment: Could someone explain the solution a little bit here? I believe this may be a solution similar to what I need, but I am having a hard time understanding some of this code.